# How to run cURL command in PHP CLI

Tags: php

I do not know if someone have asked the question before, but i am trying to run a command which is `php index.php` in my PHP CLI because the cURL code is an index.php page and i keep getting this error.

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refusedPHP Warning:  Undefined variable $conn in /Users/test/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/api-call/index.php on line 26

Warning: Undefined variable $conn in /Users/test/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/api-call/index.php on line 26
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /Users/test/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/api-call/index.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/test/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/api-call/index.php on line 26

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /Users/test/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/api-call/index.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/test/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/api-call/index.php on line 26
```

In the code below, i am trying to insert records from an API into the database using MySQL prepared statement.

```
<?php

include_once './config/Database.php';

$url = "http://exampledomain.com/api/properties";

$ch = curl_init($url);

$headers = array(
  'Content-type: application/json',
  'API_KEY: 2S7rhsaq9X1cnfkMCPHX64YsWYyfe1he',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

if($e = curl_error($ch)){
    echo $e;
}
else {
    $decoded = json_decode($resp,true);
    // print_r($decoded);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare
            ("INSERT 
              
              INTO 
                  details 
                  (
                    county,
                    country,
                    town,
                    description,
                    type
                  ) 
              VALUES 
                  (
                    :county,
                    :country,
                    :town,
                    :description,
                    :type
                  )
              ");
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
      //Clean Data
      $county = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($county));

      //Bind data
      $stmt->bindParam(':county', $county);
      $stmt->bindParam(':country', $country);
      $stmt->bindParam(':town', $town);
      $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);
      $stmt->bindParam(':type', $type);

    foreach($decoded["data"] as $decode){

      $county = $decode['county'];
      $country = $decode['country'];
      $town = $decode['town'];
      $description = $decode['description'];
      $type = $decode['type'];
      

      
    $stmt->execute();
    }
    // $stmt->close();
    // $conn->close();
}

curl_close($ch);
```

I have this code in my Database.php which connects the Database

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "test";
$password = "test";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=api-call", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not about cURL, but about your connection to your database. Your own error message is telling you this:

*Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused*

Your code ignores this error and carries on anyway which directly leads to the other errors.

Make sure MySQL is running on your machine, and try changing the address you're connecting to from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`.

Comment: i have done that but i am getting ```undefined variable $conn``` and also ```Call to a member function prepare() on nul```

Comment: The `undefined variable` message arises because your code is failing to connect to the MySQL server. It's telling you why in a message that starts `Connection failed`.  This is all in `Database.php`.

Comment: What am i doing wrong, because the details in the ```Database.php``` are all correct

Comment: @Monsta I've no idea. Your original message was _Connection refused_, which usually means that MySQL isn't running on the target machine, or that it's listening on the wrong port, or a firewall is blocking access. Start there,

Comment: MySQL is running on the machine on Port 3306 and i have changed the address from 127.0.0.1 to localhost which solved the connection refused error. Now i am getting ```undefined variable $conn``` and also ```Call to a member function prepare() on null``` on this line right after the insert query ```$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);```

Comment: @monsta If `$conn` is undefined then it's not being set in `Database.php`, assuming the code you have here is accurate. You'll need to trace the code back to find out where it should be set and why it isn't. This is basic debugging stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It has worked. I have docker installed on my Macbook so that is why it is not working there i guess it is affecting it. But it worked on my Windows 10 PC. after i ran ```php index.php``` the database was populated